# How to add fieldset in Magento custom admin form when field select value changed

Tags: php, magento

I have a select field like this in my costum magento admin form

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'category_id',
            'select',
            array(
                'id'    => 'lazadaCategory',
                'label'  => Mage::helper('test_sellercenter')->__('Category '),
                'name'   => 'status',
                'values' => Mage::helper('test_sellercenter/dropdown')->getLazadaCategories(),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
            )
        );
```

and when the select value change i need to add another fields below this select field (not like toogle show/hide just add), for example like this field

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'listing_name',
        'text',
        array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('test_sellercenter')->__('Listing Name'),
            'name'  => 'listing_name',
            'required'  => true,
            'class' => 'required-entry',

       )
    );
```

is there a way to do this in magento?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use show/hide then you can just add the field from frontend using javascript, if you need values from magento(backend) then make an ajax call on the change of the first field to a custom controller action for obtaining needed data and then adding the second field, you can do this in your custom form template